Database erased when mysql docker restarts
I have an app running using a mysql docker. Sometimes, like every two days the container restarts by itself and the database I have is lost.
This is my docker-compose.yml, and I run the docker using docker-compose -d mysql:
version: '3.8'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.33
    restart: always
    container_name: $DB_CONTAINER_NAME
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=$MYSQL_DATABASE
      - MYSQL_USER=$MYSQL_USER
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - mysql_db_2:/var/lib/mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: ['CMD', 'mysqladmin', 'ping', '-h', 'localhost']
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 5

volumes:
  mysql_db_2:

After the container is up I recover my db using a sql recovery file, and I check into the directory /var/lib/docker/volumes/backend_mysql_db_2/_data/my_db/ and the ibd files are there. But when the container is restarted I lose my data. Is there a misconfiguration, or can my data be stolen?

What causes the container to restart? Does the data loss happen if you manually restart the container?

No, even if I remove the container and I build it again the database is still there. and I dont know why does it restarts

Is this host exposed to the internet? How much effort would it take to brute force the password?

is there any way the volume mysql_db_2 got deleted? It can happen if you run volume prune after container prune.
Also we can change the volume to a local folder which wont deleted even after volume prune.
volumes:
   - ./mysql_db_2:/var/lib/mysql

which will
